# Cannot connect to X server (CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, xterm

I am running a CentOS 7 VM using the AWS and my python code is facing this error:

```
: cannot connect to X server
```

Here are my settings:

```
xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set

echo $DISPLAY


sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
#       X11Forwarding no
```